# How to set state inside listener in use_effect_with_deps?

Tags: rust, state, yew

I have an event listener inside an `use_effect`, there I want to get the value from mouse event and set it to a state. To add the event listener I used `use_node_ref` but I am getting the next error:

```
error[E0597]: `coordinates` does not live long enough
  --> src/test.rs:33:17
   |
24 |           |div_ref| {
   |           --------- value captured here
...
29 |               let listener = Closure::<dyn Fn(MouseEvent)>::wrap(Box::new(|event| {
   |  ________________________________________________________________-
30 | |                 let x = event.x();
31 | |                 let y = event.y();
32 | |                 web_sys::console::log_1(&x.into());
33 | |                 coordinates.set(Coordinates { x: x, y: y });
   | |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
34 | |                 
35 | |             }));
   | |______________- cast requires that `coordinates` is borrowed for `'static`
...
53 |   }
   |   - `coordinates` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is a reproducible example:

```
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::Closure;
use web_sys::HtmlElement;
use yew::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;
use web_sys;
use yew::{function_component, html, use_effect_with_deps, use_node_ref, Html};

struct Coordinates {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

#[function_component]
fn Test() -> Html {
    let div_ref = use_node_ref();
    let coordinates: UseStateHandle<Coordinates> = use_state(|| Coordinates { x: 0, y: 0 });
        

{
    let div_ref = div_ref.clone();
    let coordinates = coordinates.clone();

    use_effect_with_deps(
        |div_ref| {
            let div = div_ref
                .cast::<HtmlElement>()
                .expect("div_ref not attached to div element");

            let listener = Closure::<dyn Fn(MouseEvent)>::wrap(Box::new(|event| {
                let x = event.x();
                let y = event.y();
                web_sys::console::log_1(&x.into());
                coordinates.set(Coordinates { x: x, y: y }); // <- here is the problem
                
            }));

            div.add_event_listener_with_callback(
                "mousemove",
                listener.as_ref().unchecked_ref(),
            )
            .unwrap();

            move || {
                div.remove_event_listener_with_callback(
                    "mousemove",
                    listener.as_ref().unchecked_ref(),
                )
                .unwrap();
            }
        },
        div_ref,
    );
}

    html! {
        <div ref={div_ref}>{"Test"}</div>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<Test>::new().render();
}
```

How can I set the state inside listener in the use_effect_with_deps?

Comment: Does it work if you add `move` before `|div_ref|`?

Comment: @jthulhu no, same issue, but thanks for your support.

Comment: @jthulhu but I added `move` before `|event| `and now it works!! thank you. Please write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust gives you this error because `coordinates` currently only lives as long as the function it is declared in (that is, once `Test` ends, `coordinates` is dropped), but your closures are required to be `'static`, which implies outliving the scope of `Test` (that is, they need to be valid even once `Test` has ended).

To avoid this problem, one can move `coordinates` with the closures, by adding the `move` keyword before them. This will make the closures take ownership of `coordinates`, which means it will no longer be dropped at the end of `Test`.